# An integral trigonometric inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

> **Problem 1.** Suppose that $\xi>0$ and $\sin(2\xi)<0$.
>   Let $$b_\nu=(N-v+1)\tfrac{\pi}{\xi}\quad\mbox{for}\quad\nu=1,\dots,N:=\big[\tfrac{\xi}{\pi}\big].$$
>   Prove that
>   $$\mathrm{sgn}(\sin \xi)\int_{-1}^1t\prod_{\nu=1}^n(t^2-b_\nu^2)\sin(\xi t)\,dt>0$$ for every $n=1,2,\dots, N$.
>
> **Problem 2.** Suppose that $\xi>0$ and $\sin(2\xi)>0$.
>   Let $$a_\nu=(N-v+\tfrac12)\tfrac{\pi}{\xi}\quad\mbox{for}\quad\nu=1,\dots,N:=\big[\tfrac{\xi}{\pi}\big].$$
>   Prove that
>   $$\mathrm{sgn}(\sin \xi)\int_{-1}^1\prod_{\nu=1}^n(t^2-a_\nu^2)\cos(\xi t)\,dt>0$$ for every $n=1,2,\dots, N$.

(The problem is posed 29.10.2016 by Marija Stanić on page [24](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=1&page=24) of [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).

More information on these problems can be found in [this paper](http://facta.junis.ni.ac.rs/mai/mai221/f221-08.pdf) of G.Milovanovic, A.Cvetkovic, and M.Stanic.

Comment: the first question looks strange: we integrate the odd function against $[-1,1]$

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you for the comment. You are absolutely right. The first integral is equal to zero and Problem 1 has a trivial negative answer. So, I removed the first question but left the second one (which does not seem to have the obvious answer).

Comment: Maybe she was thinking about the integral from 0 to 1?

Comment: Marija Stanic has informed me that in the formulation of Problem 1 the variable $t$ was missing, which made the corresponding function odd. Now it is corrected.

Comment: You have inverted $a_\nu$ and $b_\nu$ in the two inequalities. And even better with "dt". :)

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you very much. This is a result of one night spent in a bus. The head does not work properly.